# Raspberry GPIO: Is it possible to guess what type of device is connected to the gpio pins?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

Let's imagine that someone has plugged some **sensor** on his raspberry, but I don't know which one. Would it be possible for me to create a program that guess which **sensor** is connected ?

So that I could then give him a program that would use those sensor.

If it is possible, is there a **python** library to do that ?

Comment: No it’s not possible, unless you restrict the possibilities in some way that give your a restricted range of sensors.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. It would be cool if sensor worked like usb devices, they would all have a vendorId and other attrbutes that could help to do that.

Comment: USB comes with a heap of overhead e.g. requires a complex software implementation at the device end as well as the host end. If you want complexity use your Pi’s USB port.

Comment: Let's say that there are two devices connected to your RasPi.  On one of them, setting a GPIO pin high causes a LED to light up.  On the other, setting a GPIO pin causes a nuclear bomb to explode.  Please explain how you are *even capable of imagining* that there's some way of distinguishing between these two devices via software.

Comment: And what about the **i2c** and **spi** interfaces ?

Comment: Still the answer is **no**. You probably need to learn a bit of theory of the computer buses. At least start from the classification: discoverable, non-discoverable. All, what you are talking about, is of latter type.

Answer (score -1):

The value of state can be either 1 or GPIO.HIGH or True for the ON state and 0 or GPIO.LOW or False for OFF.

```
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
```

[RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
GPIO.setup( self.PIN , GPIO.IN )
if( GPIO.input( self.PIN ) == 0 )
    self.value = 'Device not connected'
else:
    #self.value = 'Device is connected'
    return GPIO.output(pin, 1)
```

[gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/gpiozero/devices.html)

```
def _state_to_value(self, state):
    return int(state == self._active_state)

def _read(self):
    try:
        return self._state_to_value(self.pin.state)
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        self._check_open()
        raise
```

Comment: So it's not possible for me to guess **which** device is connected ?

Comment: You can read: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/gpiozero/devices.html